# Apache Server shutting down, whats the reason?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, centos

I'm quite new to Linux so I don't really know how to fix this problem.

I have a vServer running on CentOS, managed by Plesk 10. My website shuts down randomly for a few hours now.

The error in the apache log says the following:

```
[Sun Aug 19 21:31:00 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:21 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Aug 19 21:32:22 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: It is receiving `SIGTERM`. Find out what is sending that signal.

Answer (score 1):

Something is sending it sigterm, says the first line.  That will always originate externally.  Perhaps there is a cronjob set to restart it periodically?  Perhaps there is a problem with plesk?  It is impossible to say from that log what has happened, except that something issued a command to shut it down.

It's possible, given that it is doing init stuff after it's stopped, that a watchdog is assuming it is hung and restarting it.  If that's the case, and you notice it's down for a while, check that you have enough entropy in your entropy pool or change the random device to /dev/urandom (possible security weakness if you do that).  After it is started, apache will often block and wait for random data (for SSL) before servicing any requests, SSL or not.

Comment: Problem was that php didn't have enough Memory assigned in Plesk.

Comment: So something wrong with plesk, then :P